# Multiprocessing machine learning code never ends

Tags: python, scikit-learn, process, multiprocessing, sleep

I'm striving to run in parallel several machine learning algorithms (from scikit-learn) and I'm using the Process class with a variable shared between processes, in order to save the results.

Unfortunately, my code never ends. Can it be a memory issue, because I'm running 10 quite heavy algorithms? Or is it just slow?

I tried splitting the entire code in two parts (I was thinking that it would make it faster), However, it doesn't change anything...

Note that train_bow and test_bow are just float vectors.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB, ComplementNB, BernoulliNB
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier, AdaBoostClassifier, VotingClassifier, ExtraTreesClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC, LinearSVC
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier as Knn
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

#Custom class
from utilities.db_handler import *
from utilities.utils import *
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager
import json
import pickle as pkl
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

manager = Manager()
return_dict = manager.dict()

# Use a shared variable in order to get the results
proc = []
fncs1 = [random_forest_classification, SVC_classification, LinearSVC_classification, MultinomialNB_classification,
        LogisticRegression_classification]
fncs2 = [BernoulliNB_classification, GradientBoosting_classification,
        AdaBoost_classification, VotingClassifier_classification, ComplementNB_classification,
        ExtrExtraTrees_classification]

# Instantiating 2 set of processes with relative arguments. Each function
# writes the result on result_dict
for fn in fncs1:
    p = Process(target=fn, args=(train_bow, test_bow, label_train, label_test, return_dict))
    proc.append(p)
    p.start()
for p in proc:
    p.join()

for fn in fncs2:
    p = Process(target=fn, args=(train_bow, test_bow, label_train, label_test, return_dict))
    proc.append(p)
    p.start()
for p in proc:
    p.join()

# then pick te best of the results from return_dict and save them
```

This code gives me some warnings belonging to the algorithms, but doesn't show any error or warning related to the multiprocessing.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Friderico. Can you please share your import as well to simplify reproducing of situation you have and warnings you see to compare?

Comment: can you plz tell what you plan to do with these algorithms after they've finished training?

Comment: I use them for classification, I retrieve the best results from the multiprocessing and then I store them in order to predict labels of other data.

Comment: so you use only the best performing model to predict? or use all of them in some way, maybe by voting?

Comment: I only use the best one, but among all methods I also use a Voting Classifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work just replacing `Process` with `Thread`.

I think it worked maybe beacuse creating many processes is slower and some manager/scheduler/lower level entity has to deal with such processes and manage them.

I didn't start the "controller" thread, but everithing seems to work fine.

Thaks for the help fellas!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should debug in detail. Check number of iterations for your 'long' time period. Are the iterations progressing or is it getting stuck somewhere? Is your initial algorithm working fully (try without multiprocessing)? If it is then you can isolate the problem to multiprocessing and look at how the manager is interfacing.

Also please include your system specs, the general rule of thumb is that you should only run n processes for n cores on your PC

Check your performance specs on your task manager to see how much memory/cores you are using.

You also might want to start a single thread that checks whether the processes are alive or finished to see which of the algorithms are not behaving.

Personal opinion with ML, unless you have a beast PC, its slow :)

Comment: The fact is that my task manager doesn't seem to do anything, it seems like it's idling... I'll try to optimize the number of process in relation to cores. Thanks

Comment: If your task manager is showing 0 processing, it probably means its getting stuck somewhere within the processes. So could be competition, or it could be there is a bug in your training code. Have you tried running one of the classifiers without multiprocessing using your training code? I think its probably blocking somewhere preventing process.join() from completing. Make sure that the process can actually finish.